# Ubuntu 13.04: how to build Monodevelop 4.0.1?

Tags: ubuntu, build, monodevelop

I downloaded sources from git:

```
git clone git://github.com/mono/monodevelop.git
```

and dependencies:

```
cd monodevelop && git submodule init && git submodule update
```

I setup mono 3.0.11 (because
"You need mono 2.10.9 or newer"
and default version was 2.10.8.1)

I added repository:

```
cat «deb http://ubuntu.mirror.cambrium.nl/ubuntu/ lucid main» >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```

I installed packages:

```
apt-get install libglib2.0-cil gnome-sharp2 gtk-sharp2 libmono-addins-cil-dev libmono-addins-gui-cil-dev libmono-addins-msbuild-cil-dev
```

./configure

gives me

```
Configuration Summary
---------------------

MonoDevelop has been configured with 
    prefix = /usr/local
    profile = default

Packages included in the build:
    main
    extras/JavaBinding
    extras/ValaBinding
    extras/MonoDevelop.Database
    extras/MonoDevelop.Debugger.Gdb
    extras/PyBinding
    extras/MonoDevelop.MeeGo
```

But

```
make | grep "not resolved"
```

gives me errors:

/usr/local/lib/mono/4.0/Microsoft.Common.targets:  warning : Reference 'glib-sharp, Version=2.12.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f' not resolved

/usr/local/lib/mono/4.0/Microsoft.Common.targets:  warning : Reference 'pango-sharp, Version=2.12.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f' not resolved

/usr/local/lib/mono/4.0/Microsoft.Common.targets:  warning : Reference 'atk-sharp, Version=2.12.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f' not resolved

/usr/local/lib/mono/4.0/Microsoft.Common.targets:  warning : Reference 'gdk-sharp, Version=2.12.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f' not resolved

/usr/local/lib/mono/4.0/Microsoft.Common.targets:  warning : Reference 'gtk-sharp, Version=2.12.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f' not resolved

/usr/local/lib/mono/4.0/Microsoft.Common.targets:  warning : Reference 'glade-sharp, Version=2.12.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f' not resolved

In this page - http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnome.mono.monodevelop.general/14338
it is recommended «It looks like you need to install gtk-sharp 2.12.x»

But I have them installed:

find /usr/lib/mono/gac -xdev -iname "*Sharp.dll" | grep "3c99f" | grep -v "policy"

/usr/lib/mono/gac/pango-sharp/2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/pango-sharp.dll

/usr/lib/mono/gac/gconf-sharp/2.24.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/gconf-sharp.dll

/usr/lib/mono/gac/gnome-sharp/2.24.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/gnome-sharp.dll

/usr/lib/mono/gac/gtk-sharp/2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/gtk-sharp.dll

/usr/lib/mono/gac/atk-sharp/2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/atk-sharp.dll

/usr/lib/mono/gac/glib-sharp/2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/glib-sharp.dll

/usr/lib/mono/gac/art-sharp/2.24.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/art-sharp.dll

/usr/lib/mono/gac/gnome-vfs-sharp/2.24.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/gnome-vfs-sharp.dll

/usr/lib/mono/gac/glade-sharp/2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/glade-sharp.dll

/usr/lib/mono/gac/gdk-sharp/2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/gdk-sharp.dll

I also tried this advice:

http://www.mono-project.com/Parallel_Mono_Environments#Tip:_MONO_GAC_PREFIX

and add MONO_GAC_PREFIX into ~/.bashrc

echo $MONO_GAC_PREFIX

/usr

But compiling errors are still here. What I should do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's what I do:

```
sudo apt-get install libglade2.0-cil-dev 
sudo apt-get install gnome-sharp2

cd /usr/lib/mono/gac/

sudo gacutil -i glib-sharp/2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/glib-sharp.dll &&
sudo gacutil -i atk-sharp/2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/atk-sharp.dll &&
sudo gacutil -i gdk-sharp/2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/gdk-sharp.dll &&
sudo gacutil -i gtk-sharp/2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/gtk-sharp.dll &&
sudo gacutil -i glade-sharp/2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/glade-sharp.dll &&
sudo gacutil -i pango-sharp/2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/pango-sharp.dll &&
sudo gacutil -i gnome-sharp/2.24.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/gnome-sharp.dll && 
sudo gacutil -i gconf-sharp/2.24.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/gconf-sharp.dll &&
sudo gacutil -i gnome-vfs-sharp/2.24.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/gnome-vfs-sharp.dll
```

Apparently, mono's GAC does not see those libs you install from packages. Well, commands above work for me :-D

Comment: And my bacon! To help index this, I was searching for `mono-addins compile namespace gdk`

Comment: Huh, they finally fixed that. At least, package from ubuntu repository now installs everything in GAC.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to compile Monodevelop 4.1.4 today on Ubuntu 13.04. I had similar problems as you did. I compiled and installed gnome-sharp from source. When you run `./configure` pay attention to the output at the end. I actually managed to compile it without error by blindly running `./configure` `make` `make install` but failed to notice that in order for the dlls to work a number of libraries needed to be available before hand. The final output of `./configure` will tell you which libraries you need for those dlls.

Anything that appears to be missing, build from source and install it on your machine. Pay attention to the version numbers as there are later versions of some of the libraries.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend to try delete file  ~/.config/xbuild/pkgconfig-cache-2.xml. It caches installed packages and in some cases produces a total mess after installing/reinstalling gtk-sharp and other packages. You could look into this file, and if you find references to non-existing old gtk-sharp files and other then this is you case. After deletion the file will be recreated by xbuild on the next compile.

Answer (score -2):

instead of

```
cat «deb http://ubuntu.mirror.cambrium.nl/ubuntu/ lucid main» >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```

do

```
cat «deb http://ubuntu.mirror.cambrium.nl/ubuntu/ raring main» >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```

or possibly

```
cat «deb http://ubuntu.mirror.cambrium.nl/ubuntu/ quantal main» >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```