# Cannot compile Mono.Addins

Tags: mono, compiler-errors

I've tried to compile the current version of Mono.Addins, but it failed with the following error messages:

```
Building Mono.Addins.Gui.csproj
/usr/lib/mono/4.0/Microsoft.Common.targets: warning : Reference 'glib-sharp, Version=2.12.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f' not resolved
/usr/lib/mono/4.0/Microsoft.Common.targets: warning : Reference 'pango-sharp, Version=2.12.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f' not resolved
/usr/lib/mono/4.0/Microsoft.Common.targets: warning : Reference 'atk-sharp, Version=2.12.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f' not resolved
/usr/lib/mono/4.0/Microsoft.Common.targets: warning : Reference 'gdk-sharp, Version=2.12.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f' not resolved
/usr/lib/mono/4.0/Microsoft.Common.targets: warning : Reference 'gtk-sharp, Version=2.12.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=35e10195dab3c99f' not resolved
Mono.Addins.Gui/AddinManagerDialog.cs(30,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Mono.Addins.Gui/AddinTreeWidget.cs(32,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace nameGtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Mono.Addins.Gui/AddinTreeWidget.cs(33,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name Gdk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Mono.Addins.Gui/ManageSitesDialog.cs(31,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace nameGtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

I've alread installed the current versions of Mono and Gtk# from sources. Any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: Apparently you installed mono to `/usr`, but maybe you put the rest into `/usr/local` so the compiler is not finding them? Does `gacutil -l` list the mentioned assemblies?

Comment: It seems that you are right. Mono is installed in `/usr`, and gtk# in `/usr/local`. gacutil does not mention anything about gtk-sharp. But when running `make install` in gtk-sharp, I find some calls like `/usr/bin/gacutil /i gdk-sharp.dll /f /package gtk-sharp-2.0 /gacdir /usr/local/lib`. Shouldn't this install the library such that the compiler can find it?

Comment: try [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19051297/2297751) if mono's GAC does not see those libs