# Error while compiling MonoDevelop 4.2.2 from tarball in Ubuntu

Tags: mono, monodevelop

**I downloaded MonoDevelop 4.2.2 from the official website and install all the dependencies, but when I use "sudo make" command marks me these errors**

```
error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
ParamSpec.cs(221,62): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `GLib' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Placeholder.cs(26,48): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Requisition' could not be found. Are you missing error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
WidgetUtils.cs(37,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
WidgetUtils.cs(218,28): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
WidgetUtils.cs(218,47): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
WidgetUtils.cs(230,64): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
WidgetUtils.cs(248,44): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
WidgetUtils.cs(279,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gdk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
WidgetUtils.cs(363,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gdk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Action.cs(34,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Action.cs(42,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Action.cs(283,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Action.cs(295,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gdk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Container.cs(73,32): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Container.cs(79,36): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Container.cs(85,24): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Container.cs(112,3): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Container.cs(730,28): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Container.cs(735,39): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `GLib' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Container.cs(740,41): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Container.cs(776,13): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Container.cs(815,44): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Container.cs(864,41): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Container.cs(872,61): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Container.cs(882,32): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Container.cs(898,49): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Container.cs(913,34): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Container.cs(918,38): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Container.cs(933,40): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Container.cs(956,27): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Container.cs(956,48): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Container.cs(965,41): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Container.cs(965,62): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Container.cs(972,40): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Container.cs(972,61): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Container.cs(1009,3): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Container.cs(1011,31): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Container.cs(1022,33): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Container.cs(1028,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Container.cs(1084,26): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Container.cs(1096,26): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Container.cs(1105,3): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Container.cs(1119,3): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Container.cs(1121,26): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gdk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Container.cs(1134,21): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Container.cs(1144,29): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Container.cs(1190,36): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Container.cs(1204,36): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Container.cs(1219,13): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Container.cs(1259,28): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Container.cs(1282,44): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Container.cs(1282,58): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Container.cs(1315,39): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Container.cs(1346,3): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Container.cs(1354,3): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Container.cs(1402,33): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Container.cs(1418,59): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Container.cs(1431,4): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/ActionToolbarWrapper.cs(18,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/ActionToolbarWrapper.cs(19,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/ActionToolbarWrapper.cs(50,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/ActionToolbarWrapper.cs(88,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/ActionTree.cs(50,3): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/ActionTree.cs(67,26): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/ActionTree.cs(233,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Bin.cs(9,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Box.cs(31,13): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Box.cs(138,31): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Box.cs(163,30): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Box.cs(202,41): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Box.cs(202,62): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Box.cs(211,39): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Box.cs(231,30): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Button.cs(117,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/ButtonBox.cs(26,3): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/ButtonBox.cs(33,13): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/ButtonBox.cs(44,35): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/ButtonBox.cs(65,34): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/CheckButton.cs(30,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/CheckButton.cs(66,41): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/CheckButton.cs(66,62): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/ComboBox.cs(10,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/ComboBox.cs(112,40): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/ComboBoxEntry.cs(8,21): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Custom.cs(29,3): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gdk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Custom.cs(31,27): error CS0115: `Stetic.Custom.OnRealized()' is marked as an override but no suitable method found to override
wrapper/Custom.cs(96,42): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gdk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Window.cs(37,33): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Window.cs(56,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gdk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Window.cs(66,3): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Window.cs(67,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Window.cs(77,3): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Window.cs(78,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Window.cs(156,3): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gdk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Window.cs(157,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gdk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Dialog.cs(59,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Dialog.cs(63,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Dialog.cs(90,3): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Dialog.cs(115,22): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Dialog.cs(122,3): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Expander.cs(10,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Expander.cs(45,3): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Expander.cs(51,41): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Expander.cs(51,62): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Fixed.cs(23,3): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Fixed.cs(35,35): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Fixed.cs(47,43): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Fixed.cs(60,22): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Fixed.cs(74,29): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/FontSelectionDialog.cs(7,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Frame.cs(31,40): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `GLib' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Frame.cs(37,3): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Frame.cs(77,41): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Frame.cs(77,62): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Scale.cs(19,45): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `GLib' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/HScale.cs(8,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Range.cs(19,45): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `GLib' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/HScrollbar.cs(8,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Image.cs(11,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Image.cs(56,3): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/MenuItem.cs(8,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/MenuItem.cs(26,3): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/MenuItem.cs(32,3): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/MenuItem.cs(80,3): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/ImageMenuItem.cs(8,21): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/MenuBar.cs(26,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/MenuBar.cs(225,29): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/MenuBar.cs(253,24): error CS0115: `Stetic.Wrapper.ActionPaletteItem.Dispose()' is marked as an override but no suitable method found to override
wrapper/MessageDialog.cs(46,3): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/MessageDialog.cs(47,3): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/MessageDialog.cs(49,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/MessageDialog.cs(100,3): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/MessageDialog.cs(101,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Notebook.cs(127,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Notebook.cs(133,32): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Notebook.cs(143,41): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Notebook.cs(143,62): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Notebook.cs(264,33): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/OptionMenu.cs(63,3): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Paned.cs(40,13): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Paned.cs(56,41): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Paned.cs(56,62): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/ToolButton.cs(19,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/ToolButton.cs(84,3): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/ToggleToolButton.cs(7,21): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/RadioToolButton.cs(10,21): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/ScrolledWindow.cs(9,3): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/ScrolledWindow.cs(10,3): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/ScrolledWindow.cs(24,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/ScrolledWindow.cs(30,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/ScrolledWindow.cs(38,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/ScrolledWindow.cs(55,34): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/ScrolledWindow.cs(65,41): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/ScrolledWindow.cs(65,62): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/SpinButton.cs(7,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Table.cs(10,9): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Table.cs(11,9): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Table.cs(25,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Table.cs(324,34): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Table.cs(330,33): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Table.cs(336,37): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Table.cs(342,36): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Table.cs(348,28): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Table.cs(354,31): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Table.cs(384,4): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Toolbar.cs(35,3): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Toolbar.cs(53,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Toolbar.cs(92,43): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Toolbar.cs(98,21): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Toolbar.cs(110,22): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Toolbar.cs(127,41): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Toolbar.cs(127,62): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Toolbar.cs(141,22): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Toolbar.cs(151,29): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Toolbar.cs(162,30): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Toolbar.cs(170,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Viewport.cs(14,41): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Viewport.cs(14,62): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/VScale.cs(8,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/VScrollbar.cs(8,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Widget.cs(1002,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Widget.cs(1012,40): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/Widget.cs(1054,53): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/WidgetEventHandler.cs(10,3): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/WidgetEventHandler.cs(12,27): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/WidgetEventHandler.cs(25,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
TopLevelWindow.cs(10,3): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gdk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
TopLevelWindow.cs(24,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gdk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
TopLevelDialog.cs(10,3): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `HButtonBox' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
TopLevelDialog.cs(11,3): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `VBox' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
TopLevelDialog.cs(12,3): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `HSeparator' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
TopLevelDialog.cs(25,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `HButtonBox' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
TopLevelDialog.cs(29,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `VBox' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/NotifyWorkaround.cs(62,36): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `GLib' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/NotifyWorkaround.cs(62,66): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `NotifyHandler' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/NotifyWorkaround.cs(68,39): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `GLib' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/NotifyWorkaround.cs(68,54): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `NotifyHandler' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/NotifyWorkaround.cs(73,39): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `GLib' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/NotifyWorkaround.cs(73,71): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `NotifyHandler' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/NotifyWorkaround.cs(78,39): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `GLib' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/NotifyWorkaround.cs(78,69): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `NotifyHandler' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/NotifyWorkaround.cs(84,42): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `GLib' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
wrapper/NotifyWorkaround.cs(84,57): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `NotifyHandler' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
editor/GtkWorkarounds.cs(38,43): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gdk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
editor/GtkWorkarounds.cs(43,43): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gdk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
editor/GtkWorkarounds.cs(73,40): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gtk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
editor/GtkWorkarounds.cs(225,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Gdk' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
/usr/local/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.Common.targets:  warning : Reference 'Microsoft.VisualBasic' not resolved
/home/raven/Downloads/monodevelop/Main.sln: error : Could not find the project file '/home/raven/Downloads/monodevelop/tests/TestRunner/TestRunner.csproj'
/home/raven/Downloads/monodevelop/Main.sln: error : Could not find the project file '/home/raven/Downloads/monodevelop/src/core/MonoDevelop.TextEditor.Tests/MonoDevelop.TextEditor.Tests.csproj'
/home/raven/Downloads/monodevelop/Main.sln: error : Could not find the project file '/home/raven/Downloads/monodevelop/tests/Ide.Tests/Ide.Tests.csproj'
make[1]: *** [sln_build] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/raven/Downloads/monodevelop'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

**Someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong??**

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 and my mono version is 3.4.1

Comment: Even though you claim you have all the dependencies, this looks like you are missing at least `libgtk2.0-cil-dev` and `libglib2.0-cil-dev`

Comment: I have already installed these packages

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 13.04: how to build Monodevelop 4.0.1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16485826/ubuntu-13-04-how-to-build-monodevelop-4-0-1)

Answer (score 2):

This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16485826/ubuntu-13-04-how-to-build-monodevelop-4-0-1) helped me eliminate the errors you received.

Specifically doing this:

```
cd /usr/lib/mono/gac/

sudo gacutil -i glib-sharp/2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/glib-sharp.dll &&
sudo gacutil -i atk-sharp/2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/atk-sharp.dll &&
sudo gacutil -i gdk-sharp/2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/gdk-sharp.dll &&
sudo gacutil -i gtk-sharp/2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/gtk-sharp.dll &&
sudo gacutil -i glade-sharp/2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/glade-sharp.dll &&
sudo gacutil -i pango-sharp/2.12.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/pango-sharp.dll &&
sudo gacutil -i gnome-sharp/2.24.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/gnome-sharp.dll && 
sudo gacutil -i gconf-sharp/2.24.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/gconf-sharp.dll &&
sudo gacutil -i gnome-vfs-sharp/2.24.0.0__35e10195dab3c99f/gnome-vfs-sharp.dll
```

Comment: John, What is the next step after this?